# Please assist me in fixing my regex! Really stumped here

Tags: regex, hyperlink, expression

I am using a rather simple regex to make links posted to change that area to say [LINK REMOVED]. What I want to do though, is to completely clear out anything they typed with one space, instead of just removing the link itself.

I am not that good with regexes yet, so I could really use the help! Here's what I have at the moment.

```
$comment = preg_replace('%[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.]+\.
(com|org|net|mil|edu|COM|ORG|NET|MIL|EDU)%', '[LINK REMOVED]', $comment);
```

Comment: Give an example of the text to modify and the expected output.

Comment: input: Visit my spammy links at [url=http://imannoying/]Cialis[/url], EopnLbe, http://stillannoying/ Buy cheap cialis!

OUTPUT:
(the output I just want a space, so that their messages gets declined by my code)

Comment: Although I'd be perfectly happy if it were similar to the top regex, but removed all of their post. Not sure how to go about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either consume the whole comment in the match:

```
$comment = preg_replace('%^.*[a-z0-9.-]+\.(com|org|net|mil|edu).*$%is', ' ', $comment);
```

Or simply use `preg_match` and delete the comment yourself:

```
if(preg_match('%[a-z0-9.-]+\.(com|org|net|mil|edu)%i', $comment))
    $comment = ' ';
```

Note that I also slightly optimized the regex by using the case-insensitive modifier `i` and removing unnecessary escapes in the character class (for this to work, the hyphen has to be at the end of the character class though).